# Final list item in horizontal menu sits below the rest

Tags: css, menu, navbar, nav, menubar

I am so ready to be done with this website, but I'm stuck on a couple things, one of which has me COMPLETELY stumped. I'm working with Dreamweaver CS6, but I am horrible with Adobe software in general (not a regular web developer!), so I'm just doing all the code myself. I have a menu bar running horizontally across the top of my page. The final link in the menu looks fine in the Dreamweaver preview, but when I check it out in browser(s), the last menu item is sitting below  the rest. I tried to enter an image, but this is my first day on the website, so I haven't gathered enough reputation points. :shrug:
Here is my HTML code for the div:

```
<div id="nav1">
<ul>
 <li><a href="Index.html" id="visited">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQs</a></li>
 <li><a href="Rates.html">Rates</a></li>
 <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>     
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS. (Pardon the messy stuff; again, I'm just a newbie freelancing girl without a lot of experience. Side note: The percentages are due to the fact that I'm creating a responsive layout.)

```
  #nav1 {
background-image:url(Images/NavBkgrnd.png);
width: 100%;    
margin-top: 2%;
text-align: center;
word-spacing: normal;
   }
  #nav1 ul{
height: 30px;
padding: 8px 0px;
margin: 0px;
   }
  #nav1 li{
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
   }
  #nav1 li a{
color: rgb(255,255,255);
padding: 5px 5px 25px 5px;
width: 16.5%;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
display:block;
float:left;
font: 400 12px/1.4 "Palatino Linotype",Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
   }
  #nav1 a:hover{
color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgb(170,0,0);
   }
  #nav1 li a#visited {
background-color: rgb(170,0,0);
   }
```

Can anybody point out errors that might be causing this crazy misalignment? I really wish I could've posted a picture. The website isn't live, so I can't post a link, either. But maybe it won't be necessary if you spot some issue with the code. Please help!

UPDATE: Answers below have solved the problem. Thanks for the speedy solutions, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The last li of the #nav1 needs to have its padding-top set to 0px. Try adding style="padding-top: 0px" or doing something like this.

```
#nav1 li:last-child {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid to use any :last-child notations in my CSS because of compatibility with old versions of IE. Maybe I am faulty in thinking this would be a big issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from `#nav1 li` seems to fix it for me.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/THjY7/)**

Comment: I took off the padding and incorporated another user's answer above, and it worked. I'm good to go! You were all pretty fast, and I feel like I might've asked a dumb question, but it really got me out of a jam, and I feel SO much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code.

First off, I set the `<li>` elements to have `inline-block` display, rather than `inline` display to apply the block style to the outermost element. Second, I set the `16.5%` width to the `<li>` elements and made the `<a>` elements have 100% width.

*Note that this also centered the nav bar*.

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDdKk/1/)

Comment: I used these suggestions in combination with removing padding from <li> elements, and the last menu item is lined up now! Thank you!

Comment: @LadyP no problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first question by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav1 {
background-image:url(Images/NavBkgrnd.png);
width: 100%;    
margin-top: 2%;
text-align: center;
word-spacing: normal;
   }
  #nav1 ul{
height: 30px;
   }
  #nav1 li{
display: inline;
   }
  #nav1 li a{
color: rgb(255,255,255);
padding: 5px 5px 25px 5px;
width: 16.5%;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
display:block;
float:left;
font: 400 12px/1.4 "Palatino Linotype",Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: rgb(170,0,0);
   }
  #nav1 a:hover{
color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgb(170,0,0);
   }
  #nav1 li a#visited {
background-color: rgb(170,0,0);
   }
```